# Modify array contents in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

We are using smarty,

In one of our views we have:

`{if $header.showNav}...{/if}`

and if we want to set that we use:

```
$header = $smarty->getTemplateVars('header');
$header['showNav'] = true;
$smarty->assign('header', $header);
```

Which works,
But it seems rather long winded.

Does smarty provide a way to manage this easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just roll your own function:

```
function updateSmarty($smarty, $templateVar, $key, $value) {
    $templateVars = $smarty->getTemplateVars($templateVar);
    $templateVars[$key] = $value;
    $smarty->assign($templateVar, $templateVars);
}
```

Then you can one line it where you need it:

```
updateSmarty($smarty, 'header', 'showNav', true);
```

Or even:

```
function showNav($smarty) {
    updateSmarty($smarty, 'header', 'showNav', true);
}
```

Then:

```
showNav($smarty);
```

Comment: Yeah, That's what I was planning on doing, i just thought that smarty might have a built in way to do this!